# node.js & express: req.body undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently designing a simple browser application utilizing express. I'm trying to extract the value a user selects in a drop down menu. I gave each option an individual value as well and have declared the method of the form as /post.  but when I try which value they selected by going into the `req.body`, the value is undefined.

I recognize that the problem could lie with the body parser from browsing through similar questions ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320191/express4-10-bodyparser-req-body-undefined), [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237744/node-js-express-html-form-req-body-is-undefined)) but the solutions from these questions don't keep `req.body` from being undefined.

Here's my code for the app construction

```
const app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname, ''));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.set('view engine', 'html');
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

And here's the code for the post handling

```
app.get('/detailed', function(req,res){
    res.send(displayDetailed(results, req));
});
app.post('/detailed', function(req,res){
    res.send('Hello world');
    console.log(req.body);

});
```

When I post something in localhost:8080/detailed, the hello world returns just fine, but req.body is an empty (returns as {}).
The displayDetailed function is a custom function that returns a html string with values extracted from a get request from the google sheets API. Since I'm not working with a saved html document, could this be affecting the process?

Comment: how do you call /detailed? I mean, how do you "post something"? Also, you're not using bodyParser as far as I'm concerned

Comment: can you please tell how are you posting data?

Comment: Maybe this will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined

Comment: @YaminiChhabra  I'm trying to post the result of a form that consists various selects and a submit button which triggers the post. However, this is done within an asynchronous function. Could this cause the bodyparser to skip over the result?

Comment: @dropTableUsers  No, this should not be the reason, post your async function please.

Comment: `fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
 if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
 JSON.parse(content), extractAll);
  
});` Where authorize is a function calling the authorization of a session for the Google Sheets API. extractAll simply makes a get request through the sheets API, manipulates the data and calls another function to return an html string.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the time req.body is undefined due to missing JSON parser

```
const express = require('express');
app.use(express.json());
```

could be missing for the body-parser

```
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

and sometimes it's undefined due to cros origin so add them

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you setup the body parser for express to use? you can just npm install body-parser and then put these into your code.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: I gave that a shot but it did not work. However, the function call to generate the html is within an async function. Could this be throwing off the body parser?

Comment: Can you give me more details on how you make the api call and the function call to generate the html? Did you set header to application/json? I tried on postman just works with your code.

Comment: I made the API call with standard Google Sheets API commands. An example of what my code is based on is here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs. I did not set the header to json or application.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `req.body` outside of the async function (where the function constructing the html was called), `req.body` returned perfectly fine. I'll be modifying my project to account for this. I should have put this in the original question, but it did not seem relevant when I was writing the question. Thanks to everyone who responded

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue:

```
App.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```